# mySQL select with conditions replyTo

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to retrieve the comments for each posts, but now I'm trying to do my own system **'reply to'**. When someone replying, I store the comment id as **reply_id** in new comment.

```
$sql = 'SELECT cid, cname, user_uid, reply_id, 
        published, content, avatar
        FROM comments, users 
        WHERE report < 3 AND (uid = user_uid AND post_pid='.$id.') 
        OR ( user_uid ="_'.$id.'" AND post_pid='.$id.')';
```

this request return me this list of comments:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cid] => 101
                [cname] => ramzan
                [user_uid] => 1
                [reply_id] => 100
                [published] => 2013-12-08 01:44:56
                [content] => why?
                [avatar] => users/anonyme.png
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
...
```

but I want to get something  like this :

```
Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [cid] => 101
                    [cname] => ramzan
                    [user_uid] => 1
                    [reply_id] => array() // the reply if exist
                    [published] => 2013-12-08 01:44:56
                    [content] => why?
                    [avatar] => users/anonyme.png

                )
```

maybe this is a bad idea to do like this, but I don't know how to do otherwise!!!

Comment: Why do you need the `reply_id` to be an array?

Comment: I don't no, but if there is an answer I want to store in an array ( it can to be something else like response) and display this comment right after . I would to post an image, but I can't not enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe someone can help this, I resolved my problem like this :
lvl1, lvl2 have to be declare as null, only set the value of field when someone reply to a comment

```
...SELECT field FROM table where ...
   ORDER BY COALESCE (lvl1, lvl2, id ), lvl1, lvl2, id
...
```

Thank you,

Best regards